# Quickly Rotate Bitmap with Respect to EXIF Orientation Tag

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

PictureBox nor the Normal Bitmap Object does not take into account the EXIF Orientation Tag.Most modern cameras now add EXIF Info to the Images.Im using the following custom function to get around this

```
Image FixImageOrientation(Image srce)
{
    const int ExifOrientationId = 0x112;
    // Read orientation tag
    if (!srce.PropertyIdList.Contains(ExifOrientationId)) return srce;
    var prop = srce.GetPropertyItem(ExifOrientationId);
    var orient = BitConverter.ToInt16(prop.Value, 0);
    // Force value to 1
    prop.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1);
    srce.SetPropertyItem(prop);

    // Rotate/flip image according to <orient>
    switch (orient)
    {
        case 1:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
            return srce;


        case 2:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
            return srce;

        case 3:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            return srce;

        case 4:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
            return srce;

        case 5:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
            return srce;

        case 6:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            return srce;

        case 7:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX);
            return srce;

        case 8:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
            return srce;

        default:
            srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
            return srce;
    }
}
```

The above code **DOES NOT work unless i keep creating new Bitmaps** like this from the **filepath**

```
image = (Bitmap)FixImageOrientation(Bitmap.FromFile(path));
```

if i use this like this

```
image = (Bitmap)FixImageOrientation(myimage);
```

It does not work! What im i doing wrong? How can i fix this? Is there any other better way?

Comment: The simplest conclusion is that `myImage` does not have a meaningful EXIF orientation tag. To understand why that is, you must show what happens to `myImage` between `Bitmap.FromFile(path)` and `FixImageOrientation(myImage)`.

Comment: @Rotem Yes, it does.I have a Thumbnail Library which takes into account the EXIF Orientation Tag, the thumbnails for the same image shows in the proper orientation.

Comment: You're not getting my point. I'm not saying the file doesn't have the information. I'm saying that if calling your function with a fresh bitmap *does* work, and calling it with whatever is in `myImage` *doesn't* work, then something must be happening to `myImage` between loading it and calling the function on it. This can be checked by running it through a debugger and verifying if there is EXIF data when calling the function with `myImage`.

Comment: @Rotem Im not doing anything. `myImage=Bitmap.fromFile(path);`

Comment: are you saying  that `image = (Bitmap)FixImageOrientation(Bitmap.FromFile(path));` doesn't work, but `var myImage=Bitmap.fromFile(path);image = (Bitmap)FixImageOrientation(myImage);` does work?

Comment: @LeeCampbell Im saying `image = (Bitmap)FixImageOrientation(Bitmap.FromFile(path));` works but `var myImage=Bitmap.fromFile(path);image = (Bitmap)FixImageOrientation(myImage);` does not!